# Beginner FreeCAD question on axes when sketching

Tags: freecad, sketchup

I am a raw beginner at FreeCAD and 3D draughting. Watched some tutorials and designed 2-3 simple items. Aiming to use it for 3D printing.

My question relates to 2D sketching. As I understand the workflow, one draws 2D items that one can then extrude, cut etc. So one picks the drawing axes (eg X and Y), and the sketch is then at Z axis zero. After extruding, one can place another sketch on a face for further extruding etc.

But the sketch is always at relative Z/3<sup>rd</sup> axis zero.

Consider a fairly large block extruded 10 mm thick. Say I want (example only, never mind  why) to cut a 20 mm disk from the interior, 3 mm deep, 5 mm from the bottom surface therefore 2 mm from the top.

If I place a sketch on the top surface, make a 20 mm circle and use that to cut a hole, the cut will always start at the top surface - but I want it to start 2 mm down. I.e. it seems to me I need to be able to offset the sketch from local Z/3<sup>rd</sup> axis zero, in this case to -2 mm.

Can one do that, or have I missed the point somewhere?

Comment: so you want to set an offset of -2... Do you use StekchUp or FreeCAD?

Comment: FreeCAD, but maybe the answer below is what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you're working in the Part Design workbench.

So you want to adjust the starting height of a pad or pocket. There are two ways I can think of to do this easily.

1. Adjust the Z attachment value of the sketch to lower the sketch below the surface.
2. Use the "two dimensions" option in the pad/pocket operation and set the second value negative.

By the way, it is highly suggested not to attach a sketch to a surface. The current development version (0.19) and previous versions have an issue (["topographical naming"](https://wiki.freecadweb.org/Topological_naming_problem)) where editing a previous feature can change the internal name of a face causing the attachment to break. There is a solution under development but it doesn't loom like it will get in earlier than 0.20. You should instead simply adjust the Z attachment value to match the face you want.

Also, there is a very active (and very helpful) forum [here](https://forum.freecadweb.org/). I'd suggest asking further FreeCAD questions there.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful. Very much a beginner, didn't realise one can jus create a new sketch without attaching it to s face. I have noticed strange happenings when I've gone back to make changes, so maybe I have seen this issue. I'll try the forum.

Comment: This actually answers some questions I was having too. Especially that topographical naming issue. Now I can fix my broken models without having to start over.